# BadRequest unexpected token ILLEGAL when downloading ZIP file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ext.net, dotnetzip

I am working on an asp.net application using **Ext.Net** for my UI and Ajax calls (DirectMethods). I am trying to download a zip file on the server using DotNetZip. There are two parts to the download process:

- Part 1: First invoke method **ExportXML** to export in-memory XMLs to physical XML files on the server in a folder.
- Part 2: On success of ExportXML method invoke **DownloadZipFile**. This method uses DotNetZip to zip these XML files and call Save method on the ZipFile object to invoke download on the browser.

*Client side Ext.Net code*

```
Ext.net.DirectMethods.ExportXML(ids, {
                success: function (zipID) {
                    Ext.net.DirectMethods.DownloadZipFile(zipID);
                },
                eventMask: {
                    showMask: true,
                    msg: "Creating XML files... This may take some time..."
                }
            });
```

*Server side DirectMethods*

```
[DirectMethod]
    public void DownloadZipFile(string randomFolderName)
    {
        var zippedXMLFiles = new ZipFile();
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(m_baseExportFolder, randomFolderName);

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=massExportXML.zip");
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        var xmlDir = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
        foreach (var fileInfo in xmlDir.GetFiles())
        {
            zippedXMLFiles.AddFile(fileInfo.FullName, string.Empty);
        }

        zippedXMLFiles.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    }

    [DirectMethod]


    public string ExportXML(string[] kCodes)
    {
        var folderID = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
        var folderPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(m_baseExportFolder, folderID);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

        foreach (var kCode in kCodes)
        {
            GenerateXML(Convert.ToInt32(kCode), folderPath);
        }

        return folderID;
    }
```

***GenerateXML*** is the method which converts the in-memory XML to the physical XML file.

My code runs successfully to create the zip file and add the zip files, however, on the browser I see

[image: Error displayed when downloading the zip file]

and HTTP Response Code as 200 (this means no problems with the request). I am so confused why this does not work.

Please help!

Thanks,
Vaibinewbee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is probably expecting either a JSON or an XML response, but is instead getting a blob of binary data. You cannot, to my knowledge, download a file with an AJAX request, instead you need to cause the browser to navigate to a URL that will download a file.

This can be accomplished with something like a generic handler (If in asp.net webforms), or an action method that returns a file (if MVC). You can navigate from Javascript with `window.location`, or create a `<a>` tag with the `href` set to wherever downloads the file, pass whatever parameters you need as a query string, and then the browser will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I stored the Zip file separately, and on the success of the AJAX call set the window.location to the zip file location.